# What is the best ios library to handle Amazon S3 uploads?

Tags: ios, swift

I find that the default Amazon S3 library has many issues, including a strong reference delegate.

Is there an example / easy library that wraps the S3 library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can't say for sure if it's "the best" you could try the `AFAmazonS3Manager` from `AFNetworking`. I haven't used it directly in the past but know people that have.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFAmazonS3Manager

It does appear to be the only non-Amazon AWS framework I can find.